# How to force array rebuild on HP smart array (ssacli)

Tags: hardware-raid, hp-smart-array

i recently replaced a failed drive on my HW RAID 5 array in my home server. i am running a custom built machine (read: built from whatever parts i thought might fit together). the HW RAID controller is a HP P420 card, running a 5x8TB RAID 5 array with one spare drive (plan was to run RAID 6 but i need a subscription for that)

After i had a failed drive, i replaced it. i am just now checking the array and see that it is *"ready for rebuild"* but not rebuilding. **is there any way to order the array to start rebuilding?** or to give me any diagnostics?

Some other answers say there could be a problem with some of the other drives. for now the volume is working properly, and i have not percieved any data loss or performance drop (it's my home NAS)

I have also attempted to use the ssaoffline.iso tool to boot up directly to the GUI version of ssa, it works if i just dump the contents of the .iso onto a FAT32 drive (manual says dump contents on windows USB drive), but the system hangs on boot because it cannot mount the 'cdrom' filesystem.

thank you for your help

here is the situation before the replacement:

```
=> ctrl slot=2 pd all show

Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

   Array A
  physicaldrive 1I:0:5 (port 1I:box 0:bay 5, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 1I:0:6 (port 1I:box 0:bay 6, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:0:2 (port 2I:box 0:bay 2, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:0:3 (port 2I:box 0:bay 3, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
  physicaldrive 2I:0:4 (port 2I:box 0:bay 4, SATA HDD, 8 TB, Failed)
  physicaldrive 1I:0:7 (port 1I:box 0:bay 7, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK, active spare for 2I:0:4)

=> ctrl slot=2 pd 2I:0:4 show

Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

   Array A
  physicaldrive 2I:0:4
     Port: 2I
     Box: 0
     Bay: 4
     Status: Failed
     Last Failure Reason: Write retries failed
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 8 TB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
     Rotational Speed: 7200
     Firmware Revision: SC60
     Serial Number: WSD3L542
     WWID: 3000000000000003
     Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     Maximum Temperature (C): 76
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
     PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
     PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
     Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
     Sanitize Erase Supported: False
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None
```

Here is the situation after i replaced the failing drive:

```
=> ctrl slot=2 pd all show

Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

   Array A
      physicaldrive 1I:0:5 (port 1I:box 0:bay 5, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:0:6 (port 1I:box 0:bay 6, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:2 (port 2I:box 0:bay 2, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:3 (port 2I:box 0:bay 3, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 2I:0:4 (port 2I:box 0:bay 4, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK)
      physicaldrive 1I:0:7 (port 1I:box 0:bay 7, SATA HDD, 8 TB, OK, active spare for `2I:0:4)`

=> ctrl slot=2 pd 2I:0:4 show

Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

   Array A

  physicaldrive 2I:0:4
     Port: 2I
     Box: 0
     Bay: 4
     Status: OK
     Drive Type: Data Drive
     Interface Type: SATA
     Size: 8 TB
     Drive exposed to OS: False
     Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
     Rotational Speed: 7200
     Firmware Revision: EN01
     Serial Number: WSD9NV7Y
     WWID: 3000000000000003
     Model: ATA     ST8000NE001-2M71
     SATA NCQ Capable: True
     SATA NCQ Enabled: True
     Current Temperature (C): 23
     Maximum Temperature (C): 28
     PHY Count: 1
     PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
     PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
     PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
     Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
     Sanitize Erase Supported: True
     Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
     Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

=> ctrl slot=2 array A show


Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

Array: A
  Interface Type: SATA
  Unused Space: 0 MB (0.00%)
  Used Space: 36.39 TB (100.00%)
  Status: OK
  Array Type: Data
  Spare Type: dedicated
  Smart Path: disable


=> ctrl slot=2 ld 1 show

Smart Array P420 in Slot 2

   Array A
  Logical Drive: 1
     Size: 29.11 TB
     Fault Tolerance: 5
     Heads: 255
     Sectors Per Track: 32
     Cylinders: 65535
     Strip Size: 256 KB
     Full Stripe Size: 1024 KB
     Status: Ready for Rebuild
     Unrecoverable Media Errors: None
     Caching:  Enabled
     Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
     Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C778F77DA1A0B335E94DE
     Disk Name: /dev/sde
     Mount Points: 29.1 TiB Partition   0 /mnt/bindmounts/RAID
     Disk Partition Information
        Partition   0: Basic, 29.1 TiB, /mnt/bindmounts/RAID
     Logical Drive Label: 02A8315DPBKTU0ARH3S0EUA873
     Drive Type: Data
     LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache
```

As requested, the configuration:

```
Smart Array P420 in Slot 2
   Bus Interface: PCI
   Slot: 2
   Serial Number: PBKTU0ARH3S0EU
   Cache Serial Number: PBKUC0BRH5E25W
   Controller Status: OK
   Hardware Revision: B
   Firmware Version: 3.22
   Firmware Supports Online Firmware Activation: False
   Rebuild Priority: High
   Expand Priority: Medium
   Surface Scan Delay: 3 secs
   Surface Scan Mode: Idle
   Parallel Surface Scan Supported: No
   Queue Depth: Automatic
   Monitor and Performance Delay: 60  min
   Elevator Sort: Enabled
   Degraded Performance Optimization: Disabled
   Wait for Cache Room: Disabled
   Surface Analysis Inconsistency Notification: Disabled
   Post Prompt Timeout: 15 secs
   Cache Board Present: True
   Cache Status: OK
   Cache Ratio: 10% Read / 90% Write
   Drive Write Cache: Disabled
   Total Cache Size: 1.0
   Total Cache Memory Available: 0.8
   Battery Backed Cache Size: 0.8
   No-Battery Write Cache: Disabled
   Cache Backup Power Source: Capacitors
   Battery/Capacitor Count: 1
   Battery/Capacitor Status: OK
   SATA NCQ Supported: True
   Spare Activation Mode: Activate on physical drive failure (default)
   Number of Ports: 2 Internal only
   Encryption: Not Set
   Driver Name: hpsa
   Driver Version: 3.4.20
   Driver Supports SSD Smart Path: True
   PCI Address (Domain:Bus:Device.Function): 0000:2C:00.0
   Port Max Phy Rate Limiting Supported: False
   Host Serial Number: CN&6190AKn
   Sanitize Erase Supported: False
   Primary Boot Volume: None
   Secondary Boot Volume: None


   Port Name: 1I
         Port ID: 1
         Port Connection Number: 1
         SAS Address: 5001438024ECFB14
         Port Location: Internal

   Port Name: 2I
         Port ID: 0
         Port Connection Number: 0
         SAS Address: 5001438024ECFB10
         Port Location: Internal

   Array: A
      Interface Type: SATA
      Unused Space: 0 MB (0.00%)
      Used Space: 36.39 TB (100.00%)
      Status: OK
      Array Type: Data
      Spare Type: dedicated
      Smart Path: disable


      Logical Drive: 1
         Size: 29.11 TB
         Fault Tolerance: 5
         Heads: 255
         Sectors Per Track: 32
         Cylinders: 65535
         Strip Size: 256 KB
         Full Stripe Size: 1024 KB
         Status: Ready for Rebuild
         Unrecoverable Media Errors: None
         Caching:  Enabled
         Parity Initialization Status: Initialization Completed
         Unique Identifier: 600508B1001C778F77DA1A0B335E94DE
         Disk Name: /dev/sdc
         Mount Points: 29.1 TiB Partition   0 /mnt/bindmounts/RAID
         Disk Partition Information
            Partition   0: Basic, 29.1 TiB, /mnt/bindmounts/RAID
         Logical Drive Label: 02A8315DPBKTU0ARH3S0EUA873
         Drive Type: Data
         LD Acceleration Method: Controller Cache


      physicaldrive 1I:0:5
         Port: 1I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 5
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: SC60
         Serial Number: WSD30X6E
         WWID: 3000000000000004
         Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 42
         Maximum Temperature (C): 81
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 1I:0:6
         Port: 1I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 6
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: SC60
         Serial Number: WSD3LYC9
         WWID: 3000000000000005
         Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 45
         Maximum Temperature (C): 81
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 2I:0:2
         Port: 2I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 2
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: SC60
         Serial Number: WSD3JHLV
         WWID: 3000000000000001
         Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 41
         Maximum Temperature (C): 68
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 2I:0:3
         Port: 2I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 3
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: SC60
         Serial Number: WSD31XSL
         WWID: 3000000000000002
         Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 45
         Maximum Temperature (C): 76
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 2I:0:4
         Port: 2I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 4
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Data Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: EN01
         Serial Number: WSD9NV7Y
         WWID: 3000000000000003
         Model: ATA     ST8000NE001-2M71
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 43
         Maximum Temperature (C): 44
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None

      physicaldrive 1I:0:7
         Port: 1I
         Box: 0
         Bay: 7
         Status: OK
         Drive Type: Spare Drive
         Interface Type: SATA
         Size: 8 TB
         Drive exposed to OS: False
         Logical/Physical Block Size: 512/4096
         Rotational Speed: 7200
         Firmware Revision: SC60
         Serial Number: WSD31ZK6
         WWID: 3000000000000006
         Model: ATA     ST8000VN004-2M21
         SATA NCQ Capable: True
         SATA NCQ Enabled: True
         Current Temperature (C): 48
         Maximum Temperature (C): 78
         PHY Count: 1
         PHY Transfer Rate: 6.0Gbps
         PHY Physical Link Rate: Unknown
         PHY Maximum Link Rate: Unknown
         Drive Authentication Status: Not Applicable
         Sanitize Erase Supported: True
         Unrestricted Sanitize Supported: True
         Shingled Magnetic Recording Support: None


   SEP (Vendor ID PMCSIERA, Model SRCv8x6G) 380
      Device Number: 380
      Firmware Version: RevB
      WWID: 5001438024ECFB1F
      Vendor ID: PMCSIERA
      Model: SRCv8x6G
```

Comment: please show `ctrl slot=2 show config detail` for us to see the controller configuration